# scrollable Listview in mobile HTML5 / Jquery

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a shopping list application with mobile jquery. The basic structure is as follows:

```
<div>
<canvas id="header"></canvas>
<ul id="list">
    <li> ... </li>
    ...
</ul>
</div>
```

The canvas is a header at the top of the phone. The list of "li"s will be added to the DOM at runtime with jquery.

I have the following two requirements:
1. The header should remain in the same place when you scroll the ul.
2. The size of the whole div should be the same as the display size, regard less of the number of li. That is to say, the li's should appear and disappear dynamically when you scroll.

Is it possible with mobile jquery? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and there are different ways to accomplish this.  Here is a demo of one way:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/VE9XM/2/**

I modified your markup to have a jQM page div and then a container div which will be sized to the device:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="contDiv">
        <canvas id="header"></canvas>
        <div id="listDiv">
            <ul id="list" data-role="listview">
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then set the CSS so that header canvas is absolutely position at the top, and the list container fills the rest of the page and allows scrolling if the list is longer than the available height:

```
html, body, #page1, #contDiv {
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top:  0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background-Color: #555;
}
#listDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Finally, I have some javascript that sizes the container div to the display and catches resize and orientation change events to keep the div at the correct size.

```
function ScaleContentToDevice() {
    scroll(0, 0);
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var content = $("#contDiv");
    var contentMargins = content.outerHeight() - content.height();
    var contentheight = viewportHeight - contentMargins;
    content.height(contentheight);
};

$(document).on("pageshow", function () {
    ScaleContentToDevice();
});
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function () {
    ScaleContentToDevice()
});
```

P.S. don forget the meta tag for viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0 ,user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add height and overflow property to ul style. Works in jquery mobile.

```
<div><canvas id="header"></canvas>
<ul id="list" style="height:450px; overflow:scroll">
<li> ... </li>
...
```